# Find records where association didnt already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to get only records that isn't associated in Ebook model? Simply, i want to offer only ebooks that user didnt already have. I tried much solutions, one of best is:

```
Magazine.left_joins(:ebooks).where(ebooks: { id: nil })
```

but i dont know where to specify user_id

```
model Magazine
  has_many :ebooks
  has_many :users, :through => :ebook

model Ebook
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :magazine

model User
  has_many :ebooks
```

Im new in rails, sorry for stupid question maybe.

@Hass

thank you, but this generate sql like this:

```
SELECT "magazines".* FROM "magazines" 
INNER JOIN "ebooks" ON "magazines"."id" = "ebooks"."magazine_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ebooks" "ebooks_magazines" ON "ebooks_magazines"."magazine_id" = "magazines"."id" 
WHERE "ebooks"."user_id" = 1 AND "ebooks"."id" IS NULL
```

(WHERE "ebooks"."user_id" = 1 => this returns 0 records, because where filter doesnt find any row in table ebooks)

but i need something like this:

```
SELECT "magazines".*, ebooks.user_id FROM "magazines" 
LEFT JOIN "ebooks" ON "magazines"."id" = "ebooks"."magazine_id" AND ebooks.user_id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ebooks" "ebooks_magazines" ON "ebooks_magazines"."magazine_id" = "magazines"."id" 
WHERE ebooks.user_id IS NULL
```

this returns rows that im looking for but i dont know how to do this with rais and associations

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `left_outer_join` instead.

```
Magazine.left_outer_joins(:ebooks).where(ebooks: { id: nil })
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't affect current user (ofc, there isnt condition for user, but i dont know where to put it). So, this example works, but when i create records in model Ebook with magazine_id:1 and user_id:1, thats have effect for all users

Comment: Do you want to find all the magazines for `current_user` where there is no ebook?

Comment: Sure, right now it doesn't seem like there's a direct association between user and magazine. It is only associated through Ebook. Since we want to find the Magazine that has no ebook, it would be impossible to find this. 

What you need to do first is to add an association for user directly to Magazine. That way you can query `current_user.magazines.left_outer_joins(:ebooks).where(ebooks: { id: nil })`